# Check if any of the list of keys are present in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a fixed list of strings. I need to check if any of these strings are a key in the dictionary (just need True or False). I could go

```
if 'asdf' in dict or 'qwer' in dict or 'zxcv' in dict ... :
    ... do important secret stuff ...
```

but it seems suboptimal. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: read the doc for `any` ..

Comment: what are you actually doing?

Comment: Checking POST request inputs

Comment: Looks like people are downvoting the question, so I am going to delete it.

Comment: Don't delete it. Lately people have been very quick to downvote questions that don't really deserve a downvote. Not sure why. It'll go up in time.

Comment: True it is very similar. I think my version is more clear-cut, but up to the mods, I suppose.

Comment: Technically this question is not a duplicate of the one linked. That one is very specific about _all_ keys being present. This is only about _one_ key being present. Which requires a different approach. Therefore I'm voting to re-open this question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use `any` and iterate over each key you want to check

```
if any(key in dict for key in ['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcf']):
    # contains at least one of them
```

This will short-circuit and return `True` upon finding the first match, or will return `False` if it finds none.

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: how to access key inside if statement??

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `&`:

```
keys =  ['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcf']
if d.keys() & keys:
    print(d)
```

You would need  `d.viewkeys()` for python2.

Alternatively, make keys a `set` and see if the set is disjoint or not, which will be the fastest approach:

```
keys =  {'asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcf'}

if not keys.isdisjoint(d):
    print(d)
```

Comment: I get TypeError exception while running your first snippet. Should I change something there?

Comment: @Spiderman, are you using python 2 or 3? If using python2 you would get a TypeError with the `if d.keys() & keys` as you would need to call `viewkeys`.

Comment: Yes I am using 2.7 :) Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

you could try using list comprehension in python:

```
if any([True for entry in your_list if entry in dict]):
    --dostuff--
```

EDIT: CoryKramer suggested to remove the '[]' in order to make this a generator, rather than evaluate the entire list before checking if any elements are "True":

```
if any(True for entry in your_list if entry in dict):
    --dostuff--
```

Comment: Oh, nice addition. Thanks CoryKramer!